# Android EditText don't show last character

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, customization

I have this xml style of my EditText:

```
<style name="out">
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:inputType">none</item>
        <item name="android:editable">false</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/light2</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">left|center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:textIsSelectable">true</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    </style>
```

If i set too long text to this EditText, then text will end with "..." and will show just first N letters, but i need to do opposite thing. I need to show last letters and hide first ones. Can anyone help me with xml property name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<item name="android:android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
```

This might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the width of the field program, and count how many characters will fit on it, and then cut and add "..." in the beginning.

Comment: Nope. There are fonts with variable char width. Doing this by hand is reinventing a huge wheel...

Comment: [Paint.measureText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText%28java.lang.String%29)